# Font for huge display

Tags: font

For a huge display at a festival, who in their marketing uses Times New Roman, which font would you recommend?

We need it to be readable even from long distance.

Could you recommend us a [Google web font](http://www.google.com/webfonts)?

Comment: Asking for simple recommendations (without an extremely focused scope) doesn't make a good Q&A question as per the [faq#dontask]. A more useful question would be something like "How do you determine readability of a font for use on a huge display?" or "Are there special considerations regarding font choice on large displays?". A ballpark estimate of size screen size (I'm guessing several feet?) would help as  well

Comment: It'd also be useful if you could describe what sort of content you're going to be running on screen. Even if the screen is 20 metres wide the design problem is very different between showing a ~140 character tweet and paragraph text. It's also useful to know what the resolution of the display (at least high res vs old-school [LED panels](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/LED_display)) is and how far away it will be from the audience.

Comment: 'size' is hardly enough information to suggest a particular typeface for a solution. Even then it'd be a highly subjective suggestion most of the time.

Comment: Thanks for the lecture :)

The screen is the one you see to the right on [this picture](http://ing.dk//modules/xphoto/cache/43/67743_1280_1024.jpg). I don't know much about it, other than that *the dots* are large, so decorative stuff, as mentioned in [an answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/23285/5127), should be avoided.

The content will be tweets and for that we only get 3/4 of the screen to the right of it, but full height. In pixels, about 400 width.

Comment: make sure its bold, as thin lines are hard to see from a distance

Comment: @webjay: you're going to have trouble with legibility at that distance I reckon, especially if you haven't got the ability to test it beforehand. You should read [Twitter's broadcast guidelines](https://support.twitter.com/articles/114233) though, for an idea of best practices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the font to be readable from a distance, then the same rules apply as to selecting a font for small text.

When you select a font for small text, the font should be as clean as possible, not decorative. The small decorative nuances might not be noticed or worse - might cause misreading.